# WebAPI deserializing a knockout mapping null string as "null"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, serialization, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 project that retrieves data and injects it into my client-side ViewModel using ko.mapping so that it can be bound in knockoutJS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Get the data from the server-side
    var koModel = new MessageModel( [JSON-string] );
    // Inject server-side model into the client-side viewModel
    var viewModel = new MessageViewModel(koModel);
    // Bind knockout
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});

// model loaded from the server-side
var MessageModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
}
// client-side data-bound viewModel
var MessageViewModel = function(koModel) {
    var self = this;
    self.data = koModel;

    // Submit form
    self.sendMessage = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://services.mysite.net/api/Messaging',
            type: 'POST',
            data: self.data
        });
    }
}
```

One of those properties is a string. And the JSON correctly looks like this:

`"MyProperty": null`

However, when I POST to a WebAPI 2.0 service, the Request parameter looks like this:

`"MyProperty": "null"`

And when WebAPI receives it deserializes that string as as "null" instead of null.

```
    [HttpPut]
    async public Task<IHttpActionResult> 
        Put(int id, [FromBody]MessageModel model)
    {
        // model.MyProperty is now "null" instead of being a null value
```

Comment: Please add your javascript for posting the data to the webapi service

Comment: I added more detailed JavaScript at top of exactly what I am doing with KnockoutJS and the form submission.

Comment: @Nexxas, Hi, have you checked the answer? Did it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're working with JSON, you should use `ko.mapping.fromJSON()` instead of `ko.mapping.fromJS()` (see "Working with JSON strings" in [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)). And in your ajax call, you should use the opposite conversion method: `ko.mapping.toJSON()`:

```
...
data: ko.mapping.toJSON(self);
...
```

See this simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zg9gdbr2/). I've created a simple Web API project to verify this, works like a charm.

Comment: I left out `ko.mapping.toJS()`!!! So, `ko.mapping.fromJS()` was actually fine. But I'm giving you the answer because you gave me a nice JSFiddle that had me realize I had left out the `ko.mapping.toJS()` when posting the data back to the server. Thanks!